# Two Different Databases, One Locahost?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, bitnami

I have a machine which locally hosts two different databases for two different websites using Windows 10.

1. Is a Wordpress website using MySQL, PHP and was setup using XMAPP and can be accessed via localhost
2. A Second DB, created again as 'localhost' but using Bitnami & MySQL

Is it possible to have both of these running together on localhost or would it be better to have the Wordpress site hosted via a virtualhost (still on the local machine) on a different IP such as 127.0.0.2?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can have multiple databases running in one database server. My locahost (which, by the way, is just a network/loopback name and not the actual database server) currently has 16, which includes the defaults. Just set up the users to they only have access to the database they need.

Comment: This is covered in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-windows-servers.html

Comment: IPv4 network standards reserve the entire 127.0.0.0/8 address block for loopback purposes. That means any packet sent to one of those 16,777,214 addresses (127.0.0.1 through 127.255.255.254) is looped back. IPv6 has just a single address, ::1

Comment: Thanks for your input. What I was hoping to be able to do is move the existing Wordpress & MySQL DB from using 127.0.0.1 to another address such as 127.0.0.2? and then the second DB which has been configured to be accessed only via 127.0.0.1 can continue be used this way. Is this possible?